# How to htaccess redirect with wildcard?

Tags: .htaccess

I´ve got a press portal for my second tld and I wnat to redirect that to my .com domain, but this one is not working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://www.demostore.nl/persbericht/.* https://www.demostore.com/press-portal
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` only matches request URL without scheme, port and domain name.

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?demostore\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^persbericht/(.*)$ https://www.demostore.com/press-portal/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```